# can a web design agency take credit for my work?

Tags: legal

Recently, a client and I ended our work relationship and he will be taking his business to a web design agency.

I've noticed that it is standard practice of this agency to put "Web site designed by  " (which I found quite amateurish to be honest).

but what happens if the agency place that text on a web site that I designed and they just happen to be maintaining it?

I'm using CSS frameworks, JS plugins, and some stock images released under GPL and MIT licenses if that matters.

If this agency is placing that text and taking credit for my work, can I ask them to remove it?

Answer (score 0):

The important thing to note here unless you wrote it wrong:

> he will be taking his business to a web design agency

If he is the business owner then he can do as he pleases as its his business and he can take it to anyone he likes, but a thing to consider is that 'designed by blah' at the bottom of the site is often added by courtesy and not by obligation on terms of the design. Technically the design is who you designed it for, again unless your terms and contract state this... So once the design is finished, you are not the copyright owner of this design.

So the only legal grounds I think you may have is the business contacts and future work, but you will only have legal grounds if you are a state holder in the business. Otherwise again you are just an employee and designed by blah, means nothing.

Finally its worth noting this is a Q&A site for Webmasters and not legal issues, you should always seek the advice of professionals who do this for a living,.